# Any advice with date range and db date calculations

Tags: php, mysql

Please consider the following dataset...

```
RATE_ID YEAR  MONTH  WEEK_RATE  DAY_RATE
1       2014  01     364        52
2       2014  02     364        52
3       2014  03     364        52
4       2014  04     427        61
5       2014  05     455        65
6       2014  06     546        78
7       2014  07     665        95
8       2014  08     728        104
9       2014  09     546        78
10      2014  10     455        65
11      2014  11     364        52
12      2014  12     364        52
```

Sqlfiddle of same... sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a541/6/0

### Given an input of `2014-07-28 to 2014-08 08`, the result should be 4 nights in 2014-07 and 7 nights in 2014-08, so calculate 4 x the day_rate for 2014-07 and 7 x the day_rate for 2014-08. Thus the desired result would look like this:

Nights in: July 2014 = 4 = €380

Nights in: August 2014 = 7 = €665 (Only if date range excedes end of the previous month)

### Total Nights: = 11 = €1045

How can I do that.

I hope this is clear enough but please ask if not. Any help with this would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Ok, as before, the db and php results are there. The problem is, each month has different rates, so when someone chooses, for example, 2014-07-28 to 2014-08 08, the result should be 4 nights in 2014-07 and 7 nights in 2014-08, then calculate 4 x the day_rate for 2014-07 and 7 x the day_rate for 2014-08. Would an sqlfiddle help in this example?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a541/6/0

Answer (score 0):

If you have some kind of utility table (a table of all probable dates, say), then you can do the whole thing in MySQL, like this...

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM calendar c 
   JOIN rates r 
     ON r.year = YEAR(c.dt) 
    AND r.month = MONTH(c.dt) 
  WHERE c.dt >= '2014-07-28' AND c.dt < '2014-08-08';
 +------------+---------+------+-------+-----------+----------+
 | dt         | rate_id | year | month | week_rate | day_rate |
 +------------+---------+------+-------+-----------+----------+
 | 2014-07-28 |       7 | 2014 | 07    | 665       | 95       |
 | 2014-07-29 |       7 | 2014 | 07    | 665       | 95       |
 | 2014-07-30 |       7 | 2014 | 07    | 665       | 95       |
 | 2014-07-31 |       7 | 2014 | 07    | 665       | 95       |
 | 2014-08-01 |       8 | 2014 | 08    | 728       | 104      |
 | 2014-08-02 |       8 | 2014 | 08    | 728       | 104      |
 | 2014-08-03 |       8 | 2014 | 08    | 728       | 104      |
 | 2014-08-04 |       8 | 2014 | 08    | 728       | 104      |
 | 2014-08-05 |       8 | 2014 | 08    | 728       | 104      |
 | 2014-08-06 |       8 | 2014 | 08    | 728       | 104      |
 | 2014-08-07 |       8 | 2014 | 08    | 728       | 104      |
 +------------+---------+------+-------+-----------+----------+
```

... so...

```
 SELECT SUM(day_rate) 
   FROM calendar c 
   JOIN rates r 
     ON r.year = YEAR(c.dt) 
    AND r.month = MONTH(c.dt) 
  WHERE c.dt >= '2014-07-28' 
    AND c.dt < '2014-08-08';
 +---------------+
 | SUM(day_rate) |
 +---------------+
 |          1108 |
 +---------------+
```

You can also fake this with some joins and UNIONs. However, a PHP solution might be more practical, but I'll leave that one to the PHP gurus.